# can't connect between app server with SQL server

Tags: sql-server, django

I can't connect Application Server using iclock application with DB server SQL 2016. It works fine when using port 1433 but with port 2233, it doesn't connect to the SQL server. It shows this message:

> raise OperationalError(e, "Error opening connection: " + connection_string)
>       django.db.backends.sqlserver_ado.dbapi.OperationalError: (com_error(-2147352567,
>        'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server', u'[DBNE
>       TLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.',
>       None, 0, -2147467259), None), 'Error opening connection: PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATA
>       SOURCE=10.1.45.51;Initial Catalog=adms_db;UID=***;PWD=***')

Comment: NOTE: fire wall is disabled

Comment: in your connection string you do not specify port, so it uses the default (1433). If you have configured your Sever to listen on 2233 you have to explicitly specify it it on connection string

Comment: can you explain it little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

In your connection string you do not specify port, so it uses the default (1433). If you have configured your Sever to listen on port `2233` you have to explicitly specify it on connection string. So your con string should be:

```
PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATA SOURCE=10.1.45.51,2233 ;Initial Catalog=adms_db;UID=***;PWD=***')  //<-- notice ,2233 after IP
```

Comment: i can't play with the code because i'm using ADMS web server management

Comment: In most cases the connection string is a setting key on config file